# TypeScript: Record<> where value depends on key

Tags: typescript

I want to write something like this:

```
const structs: Record<T extends StructureConstant,Array<ConcreteStructure<T>>> = Object.create(null);
```

Where `StructureConstant` is a union of constants, and `ConcreteStructure` is basically a [type lookup](https://github.com/screepers/typed-screeps/blob/97948a482403d769501682a16c4d2708e758168b/dist/index.d.ts#L5404).

Is this possible in TypeScript? I can't figure out how to make the value dependent on the key.

---

Here's a complete example:

```
type StructureConstant = "road" | "tower";

interface Road {
    a: "i am a road",
}

interface Tower {
    b: "i be towerin"
}

type ConcreteStructure<T extends StructureConstant> = T extends "road"
    ? Road
    : T extends "tower"
    ? Tower
    : never;

type StuctureRecord<T extends StructureConstant> = Record<T, Array<ConcreteStructure<T>>>

const structs: StuctureRecord<StructureConstant> = Object.create(null); 

const roads = structs["road"]; // should be Array<Road>|undefined

console.log(roads[0].a); // should work (if structs was populated)
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBXAxsR8IGED2A7AzsAIa7BQC8UARPNkQCZVQA+1w2A7hPFQNwBQ-AJaluAMyLJoAJTr0oAb35QVUIgC5qQtQFs1UWgyoAafgF9BI4OMnQAKp26LlqgEaaq219HZd4IqnNBUEgoHFxkDGs4JFR0CAAeOygIAA9rXHp8WAQUNAxwwhJgAD4KKGS0jKzqQ0YXFQB+KFkGBqhNSvSITOyqX25A1Shmhz92zVwIADduAX4Q6Dg8+OkIZGx4eiSU7t6c2PysPCLSMso1ja2k4ygAQXh4IhAE8MiIaNy4jCSSv8ENgQyIRDvhNMtvhBLpttjEVgUTsQzuUAPKuABW62AADp3kRrAAKXCIAA2JIAlLwoADEQY5NlKCC8vgANo0ORUAC680B+GwJIg2JJ2AA5gS6qyAAyc7FESlAA)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In typescript only function values can have generic types. Other values need to be completely specified.

So maybe you want something like this:

```js
type StuctureRecord<T extends StructureConstant> = Record<T, Array<ConcreteStructure<T>>>

// structs doesn't have a generic type.
const structs: StuctureRecord<StructureConstant> = Object.create(null);
```

or

```js
// function can have generic type.
const structsCreator = <T extends StructureConstant>(): Record<T, Array<ConcreteStructure<T>>> => Object.create(null) 

const structs = structsCreator<StructureConstant>()
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBXAxsR8IGED2A7AzsAIa7BQC8UuiAtgEYTwDcAUKJFDrshsBHElToIAHgAqAPgpQA3lCIAuKGKgBfVizbhocFGgwAlCMmzwAJuKgQAHn1xn8sBHuFdCJYFMpGT58QBooAEF4eCIQES4eCD4BFwxxCSTNAHoUqEJBYEczbAh8XAByMgALIgA3aCIoAHMIXEYAS2QodggAOhYTAjJMvXwlXSFDY1MLOOGsPHdSLygAeToAK2NgduiiPgAKagAbXYBKJihU9IAzRG5gRrwoZBIoMsra+qaWts7uwgznVHxMDCbUzSSw2OwOJxZVzTYizLYHJQ+MYBYKhcKRPDRWK-fSiSRJChSRYrVDrQHbPaHE5dGE-LL4AD60j6fwBECB8BEE1xblhnnhLCAA)

---

To obtain the described effect you can't use a Record. A Record maps all keys to the same type. If you need a different type for each entry, you need a custom mapped type

```js
type StuctureMappedType<T extends StructureConstant> = 
    { [K in T]: Array<ConcreteStructure<K>>}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBXAxsR8IGED2A7AzsAIa7BQC8UARPNkQCZVQA+1w2A7hPFQNwBQ-AJaluAMyLJoAJTr0oAb35QVUIgC5qQtQFs1UWgyoAafgF9BI4OMnQAKp26LlqgEaaq219HZd4IqnNBUEgoHFxkDGs4JFR0CAAeOygIAA9rXHp8WAQUNAxwwhJgAD4KKGS0jKzqQ0YXFQB+KFkGBqhNSvSITOyqX25A1Shmhz92zVwIADduAX4Q6Dg8+OkIZGx4eiSU7t6c2PysPCLSMvJ2hSgAbQBpKBEKgF1NAEF4eCIQBPDIiGjcnEMAlbiUShZ+BsCGRCId8JplkCIGsNlsEjEVgUTsQzuUAPKuABW62AADo-kRrAAKXCIAA2dIAlLwoIIoYQDHJspRYXl8NcaHIqE95uzsHSIKS6dgAOZUur8gAMT1JRGZQA)

Comment: Don't think that works. I want `roads` to come out `Array<Road>`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBXAxsR8IGED2A7AzsAIa7BQC8UARPNkQCZVQA+1w2A7hPFQNwBQ-AJaluAMyLJoAJTr0oAb35QVUIgC5qQtQFs1UWgyoAafgF9BI4OMnQAKp26LlqgEaaq219HZd4IqnNBUEgoHFxkDGs4JFR0CAAeOygIAA9rXHp8WAQUNAxwwhJgAD4KKGS0jKzqQ0YXFQB+KFkGBqhNSvSITOyqX25A1Shmhz92zVwIADduAX4Q6Dg8+OkIZGx4eiSU7t6c2PysPCLSMso1ja2k4ygAQXh4IhAE8MiIaNy4jCSSv8ENgQyIRDvhNMtvhBLpttjEVgUTsQzuUAPKuABW62AADp3kRrAAKXCIAA2JIAlLwoADEQY5NlKCC8vgANo0ORUAC680B+GwJIg2JJ2AA5gS6qyAAyc7FESlAA

Comment: @mpen Sorry, I missed that aspect of your question. I first just concentrated on how to express the Record, not on "how to make the value dependent on the key"

Comment: Ahah! That's how you do it! Thank you!!

Comment: **A Record maps all keys to the same type** - this was my issue, thanks! Managed to get it working with the `K in T` syntax

Answer (score 3):

I recently hit a very similar case, the trick was to avoid the `Record` utility:

```
type FilterValues<T> = T extends 'date'
  ? Date | null
  : T extends 'date-range'
  ? [Date, Date] | [null, null]
  : T extends 'select'
  ? string
  : T extends 'text'
  ? string
  : never

type FilterType = 'date-range' | 'select' | 'text'

type FilterRenderers = {
  [K in FilterType]: (
    value: FilterValues<K>,
    setValue: (value: FilterValues<K>) => void,
  ) => ReactElement
}

const filterRenderers: FilterRenderers = {
  'date-range': (value, setValue) => (
    <FormattedDateRangePicker onChange={range => Array.isArray(range) && setValue(range)} />
  ),
  select: () => null,
  text: () => null,
}
```